# When running an npm bin'd (symlinked) script, how do I execute a relative script?

Tags: bash, npm, lerna

This is a small lerna project with a sub-package that implements a simple cli tool

```
├── node_modules/...
├── package.json
└── packages/cli
              ├── lib
              │   ├── cli.sh
              │   └── other.sh
              └── package.json
```

The tool is in `packages/cli/lib/cli.sh`:

```sh
echo "Hi..."
./other.sh
# also tried other.sh
```

which calls `packages/cli/lib/other.sh`

```sh
echo "...there"
```

The sub-package (`packages/cli/package.json`) has bin commadn "doit"

```
{
    "name": "@me/cli",
    "bin": {
        "doit": "./lib/cli.sh",
    }
}
```

And the root `package.json` depends on the cli sub-package

```
{
    "name": "@me/root",
    "dependencies": {
        "@me/cli": "1.0.0",
    }
}
```

But when I use the bin command, it runs from the `.bin` (Symlink) folder

```sh
$ doit
Hi...
<projectDir>/node_modules/.bin/doit: line 1: ./other.sh: No such file or directory
```

How do I make a shellscript find its sibling files when being invoked through a symlink? (in a way that is robust enough for CI)

Answer (score 0):

**Use `dirname $0`**

A shell script can always access its full name via variable `$0`, and infer the directory where it is located by using `dirname $0`.

```sh
echo "Hi..."
`dirname $0`/other.sh
```

**Making it robust**

If the script is called from a relative path, like in your example, `$0` will reflect that. That code will stop working in those cases if you have called `cd` or `pushd` earlier. If you need to support that, you'd have to check if `$0` was absolute at the beginning, and prepend it with `pwd` if not:

```sh
if [[ ! $0 ~= ^/ ]]; then
   mypath=`pwd`/`dirname $0`
else
   mypath=`dirname $0`
fi
```

and then you could safely call `$mypath/other.sh` even after changing the working directory within the script.